# Array pointers and return types

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to do a program that detects the missing letters if a sentence is not a pangram. I am messing up the pointers and arrays here, and I am completely lost.
I have to return a char pointer to the function getMissing Letters, and it takes in as argument the sentence to heck if its a pangram or not.

a PAngram contains all the 26 alphabets a-z.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 include <stdlib.h>

 char * getMissingLetters(const char *sentence)
 {
char ch, allchars[26] = {0};
    char * missing[26]={0};
int total = 0,i;

while ((ch = *sentence++)) {
    int index;

    if('A'<=ch&&ch<='Z')
        index = ch-'A';
    else if('a'<=ch&&ch<='z')
        index = ch-'a';
    else
        continue;

    total += !allchars[index];
            allchars[index] = 1;

}
    for(i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
    if(allchars[i]==0) 
       missing[i]=(char)(i+97);
       printf("missing[i]=%c\n",missing[i]);
    }

return missing;
 }
int main()
{
int i;
const char *tests[] = {
    "A slow yellow fox crawls under the proactive dog",
    "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.",
            "Lions, and tigers, and bears, oh my!"
};
    char * missing[26]; 
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
       missing = isPangram(tests[i]);

   }

return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are having trouble with? Also, I would suggest you read the [pointers section](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/index.html) on [c-faq.com](http://c-faq.com/), and possibly the other pointer-related sections as well.

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring `missing` as a `char *` array, but then using it as a `char` array, which should be giving you lots of compiler warnings if not errors.

Your main problem, however, is that you're return a pointer to a local variable (`missing`) which goes out of scope and is destroyed when you return.  So in `main` you have a dangling (invalid) pointer.  You need to allocate `missing` somewhere it will still be alive in main.  For example, you could allocate it in main and pass it in as an extra agrument:

```
void getMissingLetters(char *sentence, char *missing) {
    :
int main() {
    char missing[26];
       :
    getMissingLetters(tests[i], missing);
```